# Turning text in a tableview to capitals?

Tags: iphone, ios, xcode, tableview

I'm working on an RSS feed and need to turn the title and subtitle into capitals, is there an easy way to do this?

[image]

Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in the cellForRow AtIndexPath

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:@"Cell" forIndexPath:indexPath];

NSString *string1 = @"The quicK brOwn fox jumpeD";

cell.textLabel.text = [string1 uppercaseString];

....
```

Answer (score 1):

```
NSString* str = @"abcd abcd abcd abcd";
[str capitalizedString];    //  = Abcd Abcd Abcd Abcd
[str uppercaseString];      //  = ABCD ABCD ABCD ABCD
```

Answer (score 0):

[uppercaseString](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSString_Class/Reference/NSString.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSString/uppercaseString), method of *NSString* ?

Answer (score 0):

You can do it from the storyboard under Text Field Properties. 
Change the Capitalization drop down to All Characters. Test it on your device or make sure the Keyboard is toggled on. If you type from the physical keyboard it will override the Upper Case arrow on simulator keyboard.